# grails 2.4.0 - java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception

Tags: grails, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am getting the "java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception" error while running grails app. Previously it was working fine. Suddenly I am getting this error. And I am not able to run application.

Full stacktrace as follows

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
..
|Compiling 10 source files

Error |
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
Error |
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:104)
Error |
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
Error |
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
Error |
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error |
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error |
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error |
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error |
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error |
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:655)
Error |
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:523)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:183)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:168)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:124)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:617)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:269)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromModule(ResolveVisitor.java:551)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:269)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:237)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:221)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveOrFail(ResolveVisitor.java:233)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformConstructorCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:988)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:647)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformBinaryExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:956)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:641)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:139)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1259)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
```

Comment: This is already in a JIRA, in the meanwhile try cleaning and running the app.

Comment: I already tried clean and clean-all options. But still error.

Comment: Try to manually delete all /target and /target-eclipse and build it. If it won't help try to delete project and clone it fresh from repository. Do not forget about restart!

Comment: grails clean will remove all class files, means delete /target. But that not helped.
I also cloned a fresh copy from repo. Doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!!!

Delete grails installation folder (GRAILS_HOME), and recreate.

Comment: Have you investigated what was the reason?

Comment: I was facing the same issue on grails 3.2.11 with my repo. The solution was same to delete the grails version and download grails package again and point it in path.